# Flutter CircularProgressIndicator() animation is not working inside Riverpod`s ref.watch().when

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, riverpod, flutter-state

CircularProgressIndicator Screen Shot

[image]

I'm using [Riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_riverpod) for state-management

`CircularProgressIndicator` occupies only 4 pixels under any conditions

I tested on a physical device and on an emulator

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:flutter_web_lights/providers.dart';

class SearchDevices extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const SearchDevices({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SearchDevicesState createState() => _SearchDevicesState();
}

class _SearchDevicesState extends ConsumerState<SearchDevices> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ip = ref.watch(FutureIPsProvider);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      // backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ip.when(
              data: ((data) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Text(data[index]);
                  },
                );
              }),
              error: (error, stack) {
                return Text('err');
              },
              loading: () => const SizedBox.square(
                dimension: 40,
                child: FittedBox(
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`FutureIPsProvider`

```dart
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:flutter_web_lights/services/scan_service.dart';

final FutureIPsProvider = FutureProvider<List<String>>(((ref) async {
  return await ref.watch(IpProvider).Scan();
}));
```

`IpProvider`

```dart
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:network_info_plus/network_info_plus.dart';
import 'package:network_tools/network_tools.dart';

final IpProvider = Provider<IPScaner>(
  (ref) => IPScaner(),
);

class IPScaner {
  String ip = "";
  String subnet = "";
  int port = 80;

  Future<List<String>> Scan() async {
    List<String> IPs = [];
    var wifiInfo = NetworkInfo();
    ip = (await wifiInfo.getWifiIP())!;
    subnet = ip.substring(0, ip.lastIndexOf('.'));
    final stream = HostScanner.discover(subnet, firstSubnet: 1, lastSubnet: 50,
        progressCallback: (progress) {
      print('Progress for host discovery : $progress');
    });
    stream.listen((host) {
      print('Found device: ${host}');
      IPs.toList();
      IPs.add(host.ip);
    }, onDone: () {
      print('Scan completed');
    });

    return IPs;
  }
}
```

dimension: 300

[image]

`CircularProgressIndicator()` works only like this

```dart
return Scaffold(
      // backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      body: SafeArea(
        
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
               CircularProgressIndicator()
            ],
          
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image: Text instead of CircularProgressIndicator]

Comment: because you give dimension as 40?

Comment: @MohitC if i increase the dimension then this pixel will be bigger, but it's still not CircularProgressIndicator

Comment: can you try `flutter clean` and rebuild the app?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I rebuilded and its the same.
Even with 
```loading: () => CircularProgressIndicator()),```

Comment: Can you build it on web, does it happen on web too?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh on web its just error
```error: (error, stack) {
                  return Text('err');
                },```

and I have not seen CircularProgressIndicator

Comment: @YeasinSheikh with ```FutureIPsProvider``` I'm looking for ip addresses in local network

Comment: Can you try with just returning  `CircularProgressIndicator` from `Column`.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh its stays the same

Comment: What is the parent widget of `SearchDevices`? Can you try without anything, just stateless widget?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh if CircularProgressIndicator the only one belonging to the column it will work

Comment: @YeasinSheikh 
`child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
               CircularProgressIndicator()
            ],`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh i think `CircularProgressIndicator()`s animation is not starting while in provoders `.while`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Provider was causing the issure

```dart
stream.listen(
      (host) {
        print('Found device: ${host}');
      },
      onDone: () {
        print('Scan completed');
        isDone = true;
      },
    );
    return IPs;
```

FIX:

```dart
await for (final res in stream) {
      IPs.toList();
      IPs.add(res.ip);
    }
    return IPs;
```

I know what it was stupid eroor but Huuuge thanks to @Yeasin Sheikh for helping me out

Comment: I have this issue. Any idea why that fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

While the first example already using ConsumerWidget, you can directly watch and use its variable `ip`.

```dart
class SearchDevices extends ConsumerWidget {
  const SearchDevices({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ref) {
    final ip = ref.watch(FutureIPsProvider);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          ip.when(
            data: ((data) {
              return Text("Got Data");
            }),
            error: (error, stack) {
              return Text('err');
            },
            loading: () => const SizedBox.square(
              dimension: 40,
              child: FittedBox(
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `CircularProgressIndicator` is still one dot

Comment: i updated Second example

Comment: Can you try retuning text from `loading`, also Can include your provider? and is it possible your `data` will be empty?

Comment: Yes i can retun Text, if `data` is empty it is just empty list (i tested this)

Comment: I noticed that `ListView` is always **shifted to the left** no matter what values in `mainAxisAlignment` or `crossAxisAlignment` is set

Comment: Try wrapping listview with `Expanded` widget and then you dont need to use `shrinkWrap: true,`