# CircularProgressIndicator not animating

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have two widgets that both use the same Future to display CircularProgressIndicators and then show the widget once the future completes. But the CircularProgressIndicators do not animate, so they are just small squares. They animate the very first time after a full compile, but they do not animate ever again, not even after an app refresh. I have tried with other animating widgets to confirm, and they are indeed static:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _mapLoadedNotifier = ref.read(mapLoadedProvider.notifier);
    _mapLoaded = ref.watch(mapLoadedProvider);
    theVm = ref.watch(searchPageVmProvider);

return Row(children: [ _mapOverlay(),_mapWidget(),]);
}


  Widget _mapOverlay() {
    return theVm.when(
        data: (store) {
          vm = store;

          if (!vm!.hasSearched) {
            vm!.isMapLoading = true;
          }
          vm!.ref = ref;
          return SearchFormBuilder(
              initState: vm!.initState,
              model: Search(search: SearchByTermSuggestion('')),
              builder: (context, formModel, child) {
                return Container(
                    padding: PAD_M_TOP,
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    child: Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: PAD_M),
                        width: sizingInfo.maxWidthS,
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        child: VpCombinationAutocompleteField(
                            formControl: formModel.searchControl,
                            labelText: '',
                            hintText: 'Search',
                            widgetRef: vm!.ref!,
                            widgetOnSuggestionSelected:
                                (Suggestion suggestion) =>
                                    suggestion.onSelected())));
              });
        },
        error: (error, s) => Text(error.toString()),
        loading: () {
          return const Center(
            child: SizedBox(
                height: 30,
                width: 30,
                child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())),
          );
        });
  }

  Widget _mapWidget() {
    return FutureBuilder<SearchPageVm>(
        future: ref.watch(searchPageVmProvider.future),
        builder: ((context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return const Center(
              child: SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                  width: 30,
                  child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())),
            );
          }

          vm = snapshot.data;

          return StreamBuilder<dynamic>(
              stream: vm!.map$,
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  vm!.vpMap = snapshot.data;
                  if (!vm!.hasSearched) {
                    vm!.isMapLoading = true;
                  }
                  vm!.ref = ref;
                }
                return _googleMap(vm!);
              });
        }));
  }
```

When I remove the `StreamBuilder`, they both animate correctly. This does not appear to be a riverPod issue, since I have tried plain Flutter FutureBuilders and it has the same issue. I've tried so many alternatives. The StreamBuilder stops the FutureBuilders CircularProgressIndicators from animating. Why?

It is the same issue as here:

[Flutter CircularProgressIndicator() animation is not working inside Riverpod`s ref.watch().when](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72423874/flutter-circularprogressindicator-animation-is-not-working-inside-riverpods-r)

The provider:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:vepo/src/_common/extensions/vegan_item_establishments.dart';

import '../../../_common/constants/presentation/colors.dart';
import '../../../_common/enums/vegan_item_type.dart';
import '../../../_common/services/theme_mode.dart';
import '../../../_common/services/user.dart';
import '../../../application/local/form_capabilities.dart';
import '../../../application/local/map_data/map.dart';
import '../../../application/local/suggestion/search_by_term/search_by_term_suggestion.dart';
import '../../../application/search_params/vegan_item/vegan_item_search_params.dart';
import '../../../domain/vegan_item_establishment/_common/vegan_item_establishment.dart';
import 'search.dart';
import 'search_results_provider.dart';

final searchPageVmProvider = FutureProvider<SearchPageVm>((ref) async {
  final userWithLocation = await ref.watch(userWithLocationProvider.future);
  final vm = SearchPageVm(
    userWithLocation: userWithLocation,
  );
  vm.search();
  return vm;
});

class SearchPageVm {
  bool hasSearched = false;
  late GoogleMap? googleMapWidget;

  bool isMapLoading = true;
  VpMap? vpMap;
  WidgetRef? ref;
  ThemeMode? themeMode;
  Color? statusBarColor;
  String? searchText;
  Stream<VpMap>? map$;
  late final StreamController<VpMap> mapController =
      StreamController.broadcast();
  late UserWithLocation _userWithLocation;
  Set<Marker> markers = <Marker>{};
  Stream<String?>? searchTerm;
  GoogleMapController? googleMapController;

  SearchPageVm({required UserWithLocation userWithLocation}) {
    map$ = mapController.stream;
    _userWithLocation = userWithLocation;
  }
  @override
  Search get model => Search(search: SearchByTermSuggestion(''));
  Position get userPosition => _userWithLocation.userPosition;

  /// Add an array of search results to the map
  void addResults(Iterable<VgnItmEst> searchResults) {
    mapController.add(VpMap(
        position: _userWithLocation.userPosition,
        markers: searchResults.markers));
    _animateCamera(searchResults);
  }

  @override
  void initState(BuildContext context, SearchForm formModel, [dynamic args]) {
    if (!hasSearched) {
      search();
      hasSearched = true;
    }
    themeMode = ref?.read(themeModeServiceProvider);
    statusBarColor = themeMode == ThemeMode.light
        ? BACKGROUND_COLOR
        : DARK_THEME_BACKGROUND_COLOR_LIGHT;
  }

  /// Search for results and add them to the map
  Future<List<VgnItmEst>?> search(
      {String searchTerm = '', VgnItmType? category}) async {
    final searchResults =
        await _search(searchTerm: searchTerm, category: category);
    addResults(searchResults ?? []);
    return searchResults;
  }

  void _animateCamera(Iterable<VgnItmEst> searchResults) {
    googleMapController?.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
        CameraPosition(
            target: LatLng(
                searchResults.first.establishment!.location!.latitude,
                searchResults.first.establishment!.location!.longitude),
            zoom: 13)));
  }

  Future<List<VgnItmEst>?> _search(
      {required String searchTerm, VgnItmType? category}) async {
    final result = await ref?.watch(searchResultsProvider(VgnItmSearchParams(
            searchTerm: searchTerm,
            page: 1,
            pageSize: 10,
            vgnItmDiscriminators: category != null ? [category.name] : null))
        .future);
    return result;
  }
}

final searchResultsProvider =
    FutureProvider.family<List<VgnItmEst>, VgnItmSearchParams>(
        (ref, searchParams) async {
  List<VgnItmEst>? searchResults;

  final allVgnItmsGooglePlacesRepo = ref.read(allVgnItmEstsRepoProvider);

  searchResults = (await allVgnItmsGooglePlacesRepo.search(searchParams))?.data;

  return searchResults!;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you handle different state of your `FutureBuilder` is wrong, also when you use `FutureBuilder`, you should use `ref.read`, you need to change your `_mapWidget` to this:

```
Widget _mapWidget() {
    return FutureBuilder<SearchPageVm>(
        future: ref.read(searchPageVmProvider.future), // <=== change this
        builder: (context, snapshot) { // <=== change this
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return const Center(
                child: SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                    width: 30,
                    child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())),
              );
            default:
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
              } else {
                vm = snapshot.data;

                return StreamBuilder<dynamic>(
                    stream: vm!.map$,
                    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        vm!.vpMap = snapshot.data;
                        if (!vm!.hasSearched) {
                          vm!.isMapLoading = true;
                        }
                        vm!.ref = ref;
                      }
                      return _googleMap(vm!);
                    });
              }
          }
        });
  }
```

Comment: Okay thanks. Still not animating but good refactor. It animates the first time after a compile, then not on any refreshes of the app.

Comment: @BeniaminoBaggins could you include searchPageVmProvider?

Comment: Yes, added to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Just Make your own progress dialog for just do single change and change will reflect whole code.

```dart
class ProgressBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;

  ProgressBar({this.color = Colors.amber});
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 40,
        width: 40,
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(color:color))
    );}
```

Comment: sorry for some copy paste mistake

Comment: Still does not animate. Thanks though.

Comment: have you call this class?
can you share log!!

Comment: The original question was not addressed. Creating a new widget when the built-in does not work, is not always the best approach.